# JavaScript, JSON, referencing by name

Tags: javascript, json

How do you reference a JSON object in JavaScript?

I have a `JSON` response from a Rest web service and trying to reference the contents of the response which I have parsed to `JSON` by way `JSON.Parse(response)`

Sample JSON:

```
{  
   "HotelListResponse":{  
      "customerSessionId":"",
      "numberOfRoomsRequested":1,
      "moreResultsAvailable":true,
      "cacheKey":"",
      "cacheLocation":"",
      "cachedSupplierResponse":{  
         "@supplierCacheTolerance":"NOT_SUPPORTED",
         "@cachedTime":"0",
         "@supplierRequestNum":"101",
         "@supplierResponseNum":"",
         "@supplierResponseTime":"",
         "@candidatePreptime":"14",
         "@otherOverheadTime":"",
         "@tpidUsed":"",
         "@matchedCurrency":"true",
         "@matchedLocale":"true"
      },
      "HotelList":{  
         "@size":"20",
         "@activePropertyCount":"101",
         "HotelSummary":[  
            {  
               "name":"name1"
            },
            {  
               "name":"name2"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How can I, for example reference the customerSessionId? And the second HotelSummary name?

For customerSessionId I have tried `jsonObject.customerSessionId` which returns undefined. For the second hotel summary name I have tried `jsobObject.HotelList.HotelSummary[1].name` which is undefined too.

Comment: For one, the JSON you posted was invalid.  I fixed it

Comment: @ZekeDroid, if i am not wrong, shouldn't it be ```jsonObject.HotelListResponse.customerSessionId``` to get session Id?

Comment: Also JSON.parse will turn a STRING representation of a JSON object into an object so make sure it's a string before sticking it in. Can you post the actual code you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the JSON string above parsed and assigned to a variable as such:

```
var response = JSON.Parse(jsonString);
```

you should be able to access it like this:

```
var customerSessionId = response.HotelListResponse.customerSessionId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmc2oe0n/)

As you can see, you need to reference `HotelListResponse`,
so if your `var result` holds your json object, then you can fetch the values by using

```
var first = result.HotelListResponse.customerSessionId
var second = result.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary[1].name
```